# View Container with View Single Title

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a singular view residing in a view container, and I wish to have one title encompassing them.  For instance, this view's default position is in the panel, but when moved to the activity bar in another view container, the title is displayed as [view container title]:[view title].  While this makes sense, it would be nice to display my view as [view or view container title], without a colon expecting a second part.  The VSCode standard views like Problems, Output, Debug Console exhibit the wanted behavior.  They just display as "Output" or "Problems" when placed in another container, rather than something like "Panel:Output".  Is it possible to have a single title with no colon/second part?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the `contextualTitle` property of the view. Based on its documentation when launched, it should fit your needs:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_flexible-layout

> For extension authors contributing views or view containers
>
> When views are moved around the workbench, they sometimes need to be presented differently, either with an icon or extra context if they aren't in their default location. When contributing a view, authors may now provide an icon property and a contextualTitle. If not provided, these will default to the icon and title of the view container to which they are contributed.

I'm not sure they updated the API or updated the behavior since then but, if not, you will probably face the same issue I had while trying to use it. I even opened an issue to the VS Code team (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102447), but they marked the issue *as designed* and I gave up on using it.

Hope this helps